# Jmeter non-gui more request than gui issue

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

Hay Guys, I'm trying to use JMeter(5.3) non-GUI and GUI mode to do loading test, but in the same condition I get different request test. 
For example, if I calling default.aspx and setting
Users : 1, Loop Count: infinite, Duration: 3s 
In GUI mode summary report, I'll get 
Lable : default.aspx.aspx-1, Sample : 2, Average: 854

But in non-GUI mode, I'll get
Lable : default.aspx.aspx-1, Sample : 2, Average: 622
Lable : default.aspx.aspx-1-0, Sample : 2, Average: 33
Lable : default.aspx.aspx-1-1, Sample : 2, Average: 588

Why I have 2 more data -0 and -1 on the non-GUI result?
I didn't change any setting and config when using non-GUI mode, does anyone can explain this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that this is due to [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), i.e. very first response has [HTTP Status code of 3xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) and you're getting 3 lines in the .jtl results file like:

1. Sum of response times of lines 2 and 3
2. Redirection result
3. Redirection target result

Something like this in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

The behaviour is absolutely expected and for instance if you [generate HTML Reporting Dasbhoard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) out of the .jtl results file like:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/result/file -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```

you will see only 1 sampler there

However if you plan to continue using Summary Report listener for results analysis and don't want to observe these redirection responses there just set [`jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to `false`, it can be done in 2 ways:

1. [Pass the property via -J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Add the following line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```

More information [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)